# How to pass parameter through jquery generated anchor tag

Tags: jquery

i need to send parameter to url through jquery generated anchor tag.can some body please help me.please find the code below.i have written this code inside ajax code.

```
var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>");
rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['id']);
rowNew.children().eq(1).html("<a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/controller      /HelpdeskManagementController?flowName=DISPLAY_QUERIES&ids='+value['id'] >"+value['senderSub']+"</a>");
```

Thanks for the help.null value is displayed for ids in console.

Comment: What you mean by passing parameter??

Comment: send parameter through anchor tag in url